# Upsert by External Id - Different recordTypes

Tags: data-loader, externalid, id

I have an External Id on Account object.

Is there a way to make an upsert when 2 records or more have the same external Id **BUT** they have different record type?

When I make the upsert I get the following errror :

> more than one record found for external id field

The filed is checked only for externalId - and not for unique.

I'm making the upsert using DataLoader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to make an upsert when 2 records or more have the same external Id **BUT** they have different record type?

Unfortunately not. The values within that one field need to be unique for upsert to work. It might be a concatenation of both record type and the rest of the unique ID, etc, depending on your situation, but you will need to modify that data offline.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Can there be any practical use of External ID if it's not unique?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You can use External ID as a performance enhancer for queries that filter on that field, since it adds an index if there isn't one already, but otherwise non-unique IDs are pretty useless.

Comment: Old question, but it can happen when you have a custom object that can host Countries and States, with different record types. They may have the same Code for the location itself... You need to create a new object or a new externalid concating the code+type.